# Gradle не видит сторонние библиотеки

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

Обновил Gradle и он перестал видеть две сторонние библиотеки, которые были добавлены через "**File dependency**" (т.е. лежат в бабке libs/ моего проекта).

Уже чистил кеш. Делал Rebuild и Clear. Ничего не помогло.

В dependencies они прописаны.
Не знаю как решить данную проблему.
Вчера все хорошо работало, но сегодня после обновления все поломалось. 
п.с. До обновления еще поставил junit и создал проект в IntelliJ IDEA
[image: Видно что библиотеки присутствуют]

[image: Выделил]

[image: Не видит библиотеку]

Comment: Так они же у Вас лежат и подключены в модуле 'android', а использовать хотите в модуле 'core'

Comment: @woesss в модуле "core" прописан dependency {compile files('build/libs/App42MultiPlayerGamingSDK.jar')}

Comment: @woesss спасибо за наводку. Там не оказалось библиотек (в папке build). Я просто не понимаю почему до этого все работало... а сегодня все сломалось, хотя туда не лазил и ничего не удалял

Comment: Не должно быть библиотек в папке build - туда генерируются файлы при сборке, а Rebuild и Clear её очищают.

Comment: @woesss тогда я в тупике. Не знаю как все вернуть в рабочее состояние. Но когда перенес jar файлы это помогло...

Comment: Положите их в папку libs (создайте, если её нет) в модуле 'core', в его же gradle укажите путь к ним `compile files('libs/App42MultiPlayerGamingSDK.jar')` - пути здесь указываются относительно папки, в которой лежит сам gradle.build. Можно указать всё содержимое папки libs: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` - тогда не нужно будет каждый jar прописывать отдельно